# CRC implementation in python

Tags: python, networking, crc, crc16

Here is my code for the implementation of a CRC in python:

```
import math

divisors  = [0b1100000001111, 0b11000000000000101, 0b10001000000100001, 0b1011, 0b10011,0b00000111, 0b11001]

def get_Length(arg):
    return math.floor(math.log2(arg)) +1

def CRC(message, type):
    print("Message ",bin(message)[2:], hex(message))
    # int message_length = get_Length(message);
    divisor_length = get_Length(divisors[type])
    divisor = divisors[type]
    print("Divisor: ",bin(divisor)[2:], hex(divisor))
    message = message << (divisor_length-1)

    old_message = message
    while( (message >> (divisor_length-1)) !=0 ):
        ml = get_Length(message)

        divisor_copy = divisor << (ml-divisor_length)

        message = message ^ divisor_copy

    print(bin(message)[2:], hex(message))
    print(bin(old_message| message)[2:], hex(old_message|message), end="\n\n")

def main():
   CRC(0b1101011011, 4)
   CRC(0x34ec, 1)
main()
```

The first message is from this [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Computation) and gives the correct result. However the second one (*x34ec*), which demonstrates a CRC-16 is not giving the correct result ([correct result](https://crccalc.com/?crc=34ec&method=crc16&datatype=hex&outtype=hex)). I'm attaching the output snapshot as well:

[image].

It would be appreciative if somebody can shed some light on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your result matches the CRC-16/BUYPASS result in that table.

Comment: @TimRoberts What about the ARC? Also, another question what is the significance of the Check column in the link given above?

Comment: I don't know what "Check" means.  You can look at the web page.  They send each one to a web service for the computation.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179867/crc16-modbus-computing-algorithm

Comment: Yes, thanks -- the "Check" column is the result of running the checksum on the ASCII characters "123456789".

Comment: As for ARC, you have implemented the CRC-16/BUYPASS algorithm.  If you wanted CRC-16/ARC, then you did it wrong.

Comment: @Tim  could please tell what are the extra steps do I need to do, to go from CRC-16/BUYPASS to ARC?

Comment: You can use Google just as easily as I can.  ARC has the same polynomial as BUYPASS, but the bits are reversed on the way in, and on the way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many CRC-16's. I count [30 here alone](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm), and I'm sure there are more in use that are not in that catalog.

The one you have implemented is the CRC-16/UMTS in that catalog, also known as CRC-16/BUYPASS and CRC-16/VERIFONE. It is the most straightforward of definitions, with the bits in and bits out not reflected, with an initial value of zero, and with no final exclusive-or.

The result CRC you implemented on the message `34 ec` *can* in fact be found directly in your linked "correct result", on the fourth row of the table which is labeled "CRC-16/BUYPASS".

If you want to implement a *different* CRC-16, the first thing you need to do is specify *which one*. That specification is the polynomial, reflection of input and output, initial value, and final exclusive-or value.